# How to replace the griffon app icon for a custom icon

Tags: griffon

I want to replace the Griffon icon for a custom icon for my App. I have replaced the icons in my view as shown here:

```
application(id: "mainFrame", title: 'selekron',
  preferredSize: [884, 800],
  pack: true,
  //location: [50,50],
  locationByPlatform:true,
  iconImage: imageIcon('/progresomusica-icon-48x48.png').image,
  iconImages: [imageIcon('/progresomusica-icon-48x48.png').image,
               imageIcon('/progresomusica-icon-32x32.png').image,
               imageIcon('/progresomusica-icon-16x16.png').image]) {
```

I have the next settings in griffon-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy:

```
deploy {
    application {
        title = "${appName} ${appVersion}"
        vendor = System.properties['user.name']
        homepage = "http://localhost/${appName}"
        description {
            complete = "${appName} ${appVersion}"
            oneline  = "${appName} ${appVersion}"
            minimal  = "${appName} ${appVersion}"
            tooltip  = "${appName} ${appVersion}"
        }
        icon {
            'default' {
                name   = 'progresomusica-icon-64x64.png'
                width  = '64'
                height = '64'
            }
            splash {
                name   = 'griffon.png'
                width  = '391'
                height = '123'
            }
            selected {
                name   = 'progresomusica-icon-64x64.png'
                width  = '64'
                height = '64'
            }
            disabled {
                name   = 'progresomusica-icon-64x64.png'
                width  = '64'
                height = '64'
            }
            rollover {
                name   = 'progresomusica-icon-64x64.png'
                width  = '64'
                height = '64'
            }
            shortcut {
                name   = 'progresomusica-icon-64x64.png'
                width  = '64'
                height = '64'
            }
        }
```

I have deleted my $HOME/.griffon folder and run the app again but I keep getting the griffon red icon.

Any ideas about what am I missing?

Comment: did you do a 'griffon clean' ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the application on OSX? If so then have a look at $GRIFFON_HOME/scripts/_GriffonPackage.groovy. This file defines the following closure

```
resolveApplicationIcnsFile = {
    File icnsFile = null
    if (buildConfig.application.icon) {
        icnsFile = new File(basedir, buildConfig.application.icon)
        if (!icnsFile.exists()) icnsFile = null
    }
    if (icnsFile == null) {
        icnsFile = new File(basedir, "griffon-app/conf/dist/shared/${griffonAppName}.icns")
        if (!icnsFile.exists()) icnsFile = null
    }
    if (icnsFile == null) {
        icnsFile = new File("${griffonHome}/media/griffon.icns")
    }
    icnsFile
}
```

Basically you have 2 choices for defining the icon to be used in OSX's dock otherwise the default icon gets chosen. If running the app on Windows or Linux then updating the main View (as you did) should be enough

```
  iconImage: imageIcon('/progresomusica-icon-48x48.png').image,
  iconImages: [imageIcon('/progresomusica-icon-48x48.png').image,
               imageIcon('/progresomusica-icon-32x32.png').image,
               imageIcon('/progresomusica-icon-16x16.png').image]) {
```